# Ionic nested views load on each other

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-routing, angular-ui-router

Here's my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IWGxje?p=preview) .

```
        .state('tabs', {
            url: "/tab",
            abstract: true,
            cache: false,
            templateUrl: "tabs.html"
//            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })

        .state('tabs.home', {
            url: "/home",
            cache: false,
            views: {
                'home-tab': {
                    templateUrl: "home.html"
//                    controller: 'welcomeController'
                }
            }

        })

        .state('tabs.list', {
            url: "/list",
            cache: false,
            views: {
                'category-tab': {
                    templateUrl: "list.html"
//                  
                }
            }

        })


    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/home');
```

Now when i switch between views , views load on each other and you can see both of them .  or better to say : Url change but views don't change.

Am i missing something ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have forgort to wrap you list.html content inside `ion-view`

**List.html**

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-royal">
    <h1 class="title">
list
</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content class="">
    <button class="button btn-custom button-full button-assertive icon icon-left ion-android-bicycle no-border red-custom no-margin">
      Sport
    </button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

[**Demo here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qf8CRSCGFqfN0eJ2dTpa?p=preview)

Comment: thanks,now when you click on category and after that click on home , Home doesn't load up

Comment: now it working with this : <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-royal">

    <ion-tab title="خانه"
             icon="ion-home"
             href="#/tab/home">
        <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="آرشیو" icon="ion-ios-people"
             href="#/tab/category">
        <ion-nav-view name="category-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>



</ion-tabs>

Comment: can i ask you something ? how can i add sub page but not in tab ?

Comment: please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159599/nested-views-but-not-in-tab-bar-ionic